# How can I open an application from another application and then open a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, twitter-bootstrap

We have two browser applications. One application (app1) wants to open another application (app2), send data in its URL, open a bootstrap modal in app2, and fill out the fields with the data sent from app1. Is this possible?

I'm pretty sure it is possible to send data from app1 to app2 through an URL, but the opening of the popup modal is what I don't understand how to do. Once the data is sent via URL, we need to click on the link that opens the popup modal and have the fields filled in. But how would we trigger the opening of the modal popup after the url data transfer ?

here is our modal.

```
var $modal      = ich.auth({
                            title   : "Authorize",
                            base    : getCategory(type),
                            buttons : [{ id : 'submit',   label : 'Submit', classes : 'btn-primary' },
                                       { id : 'cancel', label : 'Cancel' }]
                            })
```

I'm attaching a picture for clarification. 
[image]

Comment: Can't you just launch the modal on page load?

Comment: I'll be honest, i'm not that familiar with this process, and my coworkers thought it couldn't be done. I'm not sure why we couldn't just trigger a click event on the link to open the popup after sending the data via URL, that's why i opened it up as a question to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate a physical click you will probably want to use the jquery trigger function.

Here is the example from the jquery documentation:

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
$( "#foo" ).trigger( "click" );
```

Here is the link to the actual documentation for further reading: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

The general idea is that trigger() will trigger any events bound to that object, so if you wire it up to be clickable using on() (documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)) then calling trigger() will fire the click event just as if it had been clicked.

Comment: why not just open with modal api?

Comment: @charlietfl see my comment on the question, I was under the impression that the asker wanted to simulate a mouse click hence my answer